# Book about a man who goes forward in time while sitting in his chair

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

The book was probably written in the 60-70s, and I think I read it in the mid-1980s. The story from what I can recall was that of a man who went forward in time while he was in the confines of his room. He was sat in his chair and when he stood he turned to see his decayed corpse still sitting in the chair. Later in the book there where creatures who came out of a hole in his garden who resembled those from H.G. Wells's time machine. I think the book was more of a novella and it was first person narrative like he was writing a diary.

Comment: Try editing the title of the question to be a little more specific. It'll draw in more people.

Comment: I'm going forward in time while sitting in my chair as we speak...

Comment: @dlanod Watch out for Morlocks!!!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Giles.                                  There was no story as such.Just a narrative on what the man was experiencing.it was very cerebral as he never left the room.

Comment: Doesn't H.G. Wells Time Machine read exactly like that? The machine was in his room, it had a chair, he went forward in time in it... It was like a diary (first person account). What am I missing here? Oh, the corpse bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sound like "House on the borderlands" by William Hope Hodgeson, although it is much older than the 60s.

Comment: That's the one! Many thanks. Just grabbed from kindle and Wow! 1907?.

Comment: Many thanks. Just pulled from kindle and Wow!!1907? Written slightly earlier than I thought. I must have read a 1970s re-print.